# Getting TypeScript compile error when attempting prop drilling of state objects in Ionic/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, jsx, react-props

I’m trying to drill app state down through component props in app.tsx, but get a typescript error:

```
Type '{ dailyObd: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, {}>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & obds & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'dailyObd' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & obds & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

It points to the source of the error being "dailyObd" in `<Today dailyObd...` in App's return.

Here’s a breakdown of what I’ve got:
app.tsx:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [dailyObds, setDailyObds] = useState<dailyObds>([{
    title: 'First',
    completed: false
  }])

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
          <Menu />
          <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
            <Route path="/page/today" render={(dailyObds)=>(<Today dailyObd={dailyObds} /> )} />
            <Redirect from="/" to="/page/Inbox" exact />
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonSplitPane>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  )
}

interface dailyObd{
    title: string
    completed: boolean
}
interface dailyObds extends Array<dailyObd>{}

export default App;
```

Here’s Today.tsx:

```
const Today: React.FC = ({ dailyObd })=>{
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start"><IonMenuButton /></IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Today</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonText>Some stuff will go here... eventually.</IonText>>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  )
}
export default Today
```

I set strict to false in tsconfig.json, but I still can’t compile because of the listed error. What am I missing here? Why is it seemingly so difficult to add a prop to a component with TypeScript? Thanks for any help, I am new to Ionic/React/TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the typings for your `Today` component. From what I can see, the `Today` component accepts `dailyObd` as the props, so you will need to create an interface or type genetic for the component.

In addition, you might want to rename your `dailyObd` interface to use upper camelcase instead, as this is one of the naming conventions for classes/interfaces.

```
interface DailyObd {
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

Now, you can provide the generic type parameter for `Today`.

```
interface TodayProps {
  dailyObd: DailyObd[];
}

const Today: React.FC<TodayProps> = ({ dailyObd }) => { ... }
```

Comment: if you take a second look, the component is an `IonPage` which is probably accessed through the `IonRouter` so it will require the inclusion of `RouteComponentProps`

Comment: @AaronSaunders
Thank you, I implemented the interface and have it extending RouteComponentProps.
Now it is throwing this error on the <Today /> component in its route's render prop:
Type '{ dailyObd: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, {}>; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TodayProps': history, location, match  TS2739

Comment: Ahh.. Hmm.. I didn't know you need to extend it with `RouteComponentProps`. It wasn't exactly exported with the router per se.

Comment: @RobertRobinson how about implementing the interface without extending it with `RouteComponentProps `?

Comment: @wentjun I tried that, still had the same issue. I resolved that, however, by doing as you first suggested and correcting the interface naming to convention. The issue was that "dailyObd" in TodayProps was not typed to anything; I was able to see that once I fixed the naming convention. once I typed it as DailyObds, that issue resolved, but another appeared:
Type 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, PoorMansUnknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'DailyObds': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740)

Comment: @wentjun so it seems that the dailyObd prop in <Today /> is somehow not being typed with all of the properties of an array. I don't know how this is possible since it extends Array<DailyObd>.

Comment: Ahh I see.. If it is supposed to be an array, perhaps you should use this instead in the interface? `dailyObd: DailyObd[];`? I have updated my answer

Comment: @wentjun thanks so much for your help! Unfortunately, changing the type of "dailyObd" to "DailyObd[]" did not resolve the error :-(

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have resolved the next issue which popped up after I applied typing to the Today component as wentjun suggested.
Following the comments on wentjun's answer, I eventually found that in the route's render prop, the variable passed into the anonymous function is not the state variable that I had created, despite it sharing the same name. When I removed that variable from the anonymous function declaration, I found that the state variable that I created was then being passed into the Today component as it was created and the application is working as expected now. Here's the TS I settled on:

App.tsx:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  const [dailyObds, setDailyObds] = useState<DailyObd[]>([{
    title: 'first',
    completed: false
  },{
    title: 'second',
    completed: true
  }])

  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
          <Menu />
          <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
            <Route path="/page/today" render={()=>(<Today dailyObdsProp={dailyObds} /> )} />
            <Redirect from="/" to="/page/Inbox" exact />
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonSplitPane>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  )
}

interface DailyObd{
  title: string
  completed: boolean
}

export default App
```

Today.tsx:

```
const Today: React.FC<Today> = (dailyObdsProp)=>{
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start"><IonMenuButton /></IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Today's Obds</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonText>
          {
            dailyObdsProp.dailyObdsProp.map(
              obd=>(
                <p>{obd.title} - {obd.completed ? 'Completed' : 'Uncomplete'}</p>
              )
            )
          }
        </IonText>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  )
}

interface Today{
  dailyObdsProp: DailyObd[]
}
interface DailyObd{
  title: string
  completed: boolean
}
export default Today
```

Thanks everyone for your help! Please let me know if there's an issue with this solution.

Comment: Good job on figuring this out!